# Get asset Id by AssetType Name using REST API

Tags: rest, oracle11g, fatwire, webcenter-sites

We need to get the id of asset by its Name.
For e.g. if asset name in "AVISports"

> http://localhost:8080/cs/REST/sites/{SiteName}/AVISports

It give me the details about AVISports asset, but we need, what is the asset Id for this.
Can anyone here please tell me, how to get ID from by Asset Name.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Techies, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

http://localhost:8080/cs/REST/sites/{SiteName}/search?field:name:equals={some asset name}